# Grouped bar chart with second y-axis (pstricks)

Tags: pstricks, bar-chart

I've already found the examples of the pstricks module pst-bar (e.g., https://www.muskmelon.jp/tex/pstricks/pst-bar/pst-bar-doc.pdf) which are working quite good. With psbarchart, I realize a grouped bar charts with two bars. But: Is there a possibility to add a second y-axis (in order to scale one of my two bars)?

```
\readpsbardata[ignoreLines=1]{\data}{values.csv}

\psgraph[Dx=1,Dy=0.25,comma]{->}(0,0)(9.5,1){7cm}{4cm}
    \psset{linecolor=black,linewidth=0.5pt,showpoints=false, plotstyle=line}
    \psbarchart[barstyle={red,blue}]{\data}
\endpsgraph
```

with the data (of values.csv):

```
Method1, Method2, Method3
0.01, 0.01, 0.01
4.00, 5.41, 4.25
```

Due to my other graphs and plots with pstricks in my thesis, I would like to stick pstricks.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  It is usually best to provide a complete minimal document demonstrating the problem in addition to/instead of code snippets.

Comment: are you looking for something like this: `\psbarchart[yunit=0.2,barstyle={red,blue}]{\data}`

Comment: Not directly. I would like to add a second y-axis so that one axis refer to the red bars and one to the blue bars (and for this second axis the scaling should be adjusted). But the question how to add a second axis?

Comment: see my answer ...

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
[...]
\rput(9.5,0){%
    \psaxes[xAxis=false,Dy=2,dy=0.25,
            showorigin=false,ylabelPos=right]{->}(-3,1)[x,0][$y_2$,90]}
\endpsgraph
```

Comment: So, I've to add the second axis manually? Ok, thanks a lot. That's the way I am going to handle it...